# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pylot (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pylot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Error while installing a package:

```
pip install matplotlib.pylot
```

and i'm getting an error as Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pylot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pylot

Comment: You should put the error message in here so we could understand the problem better.

Comment: Install [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), which is available for Windows, Mac & Linux.

Answer (score 4):

The module you need to install is only matplotlib

try this:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called py**p**lot, not pylot.

Instead of..:

```
pip install matplotlib.pylot
```

... try:

```
pip install matplotlib.pyplot
```